# window.location Problem in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this simple code that is working fine in every browser, but NOT in IE (every version).

```
 window.setTimeout('window.location = \"http://www.domain/modules/yobilab/copyright/classes/GO_overview.php?refNumb=".$RefNumb."\"', 3000);
            return false;
```

In every browser it will go to the right link

In IE instead it includes also the Link where it comes from, so it will become something like this:

```
http://www.domain/PAGEWHEREIWAS/modules/yobilab/copyright/classes/GO_overview.php?refNumb=something
```

Why it is doing so?

It generates a NOT FOUND error obviously.

Comment: Doesn't look "simple" to me. What on earth does `\"http://www.domain/modules/yobilab/copyright/classes/GO_overview.php?refNumb=".$RefNumb."\"` mean in Javascript?

Comment: Sorry that is also a combination of PHP. Just look the javascript code and forget PHP

Comment: No. Abstract the PHP out of the question entirely so that we can be sure it is not causing your problem. And provide a live testcase on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: That looks disturbingly like you are generating a JS string using PHP, and that JS string is being passed to `setTimeout` to be `eval`ed. Gargh! If you are going to dynamically build a URI in PHP, then store it in a variable so it is more readable. If you are going to use `setTimeout` then pass it a function, not a string.

Comment: Did you try window.location.href = "http://url/to/goto"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `document.location` instead of `window.location`.

Comment: This solved the issue..I will accept your answer in 4 minutes =D Thanks everybody for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {window.location = "http://www.domain/modules/yobilab/copyright/classes/GO_overview.php?refNumb=12"}, 3000);
```

Comment: What does it do actually?

Answer (score 1):

Add a "/" before the link, this makes IE understand that it is a relative link and forces the correct redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirect() { 
     window.location.href = "http://www.domain/PAGEWHEREIWAS/modules/yobilab/copyright/classes/GO_overview.phprefNumb=something"; 

}

setTimeout(redirect, 3000);
```