# window.location.href not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I am using Jquery Ajax for login form.After ajax success,I redirect the page using `window.location.href="test.php"`

This is working fine in Chrome,firefox and also in IE9.But in IE 11,it is not working.

I have tried,

```
window.location.replace("test.php");
window.location.assign("test.php");
setTimeout('window.navigate("test.php");', 1);
window.open('test.php','_self', null , false);
```

But all fails.Can anyone help?

Comment: Ever tried window.location = "test.php";

Comment: How it fails? What error do you get? `location.href = 'myurl';` works just fine

Comment: These two also not working.In console,the filename is just echoed as File: test.php but i didn't give any console statement.

Comment: As they say: If you make it work for IE it will break on all other browsers, and if you make it work on IE it won't work on any other browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a leading slash:

```
window.location.assign('/test.php');
```

**Explanation**
Whenever setting the location, it works very similar to clicking a hyperlink on the same page. So let's say you're at a location like this:

> http://yourdomain.com/this/is/a/very/long/path.php

... and then you try to navigate away from this page with any of the following mechanisms *without a leading slash*:

```
<a href="test.php">Test Page</a>
window.location = "test.php";
window.location.href = "test.php";
window.location.assign("test.php");
window.location.replace("test.php");
window.history.pushState("Test Page", {}, "test.php");
```

... you will notice the URL become this:

> http://yourdomain.com/this/is/a/very/long/path.php

But if you put a leading slash, **/test.php**, then the location becomes this:

> http://yourdomain.com/test.php

Comment: @rekhas So the actual problem was about the leading `/` that was missing? Because in your question you mention that you tried `window.location.assign("test.php");`

Answer (score 4):

Regarding session storage, you have to make settings as follows,

Go to Tools->Internet Options and click Privacy Tab and select Advanced and in that window,check the box Override Automatic Cookie handling and Always allow Session cookies check box.

It will work.It works for me fine.

Regards,
Rekha

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.location` instead, it works in IE11 as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297374/1059101).

```
document.location.href = "test.php";
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really correct. I also came across this answer once, but I never was able to confirm that. There where more sites and also answers here that say the opposite e.g. [window.location vs. document.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857878) (and its duplicate). Maybe the problem there was that `window.location` was used in a string passed to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @t.niese i am also not sure but i found this answer on SO, so i suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem like this:

```
window.location.replace("test.php");
```

I would recommend `location.assign("url")` or `location.replace("url")` instead of `location.href = url`.