# Javascript search form code

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a search form that I'd like to use on my website to enter text in one box and use radio buttons to choose the search engine (either a site search or my library's catalog).

This code works in Firefox and Chrome but not IE and Safari:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosearch() {
var sf=document.searchform;
var submitto = sf.sengines.value + escape(sf.searchterms.value);
window.location.href = submitto;
return false;
}
</script>

<form name="searchform" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
<input type="text" name="searchterms" size="20">
<input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search">
<br />
<input type="radio" name="sengines" checked value="http://chelmsford.mvlc.org/search/keyword/">Catalog &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="sengines" value="http://chelmsfordlibrary.org/?s=">Site
</form>
```

And I also have this code, which works in IE but not in Firefox:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var engine = document.forms[0];
var txt = "";
var term = escape(document.radiosearch.searchterms.value)
var i;
for (i = 0; i < engine.length; i++) {
    if (engine[i].checked) {
        txt = txt + engine[i].value;
    }
}
window.location.href = txt + term;
}
</script>

<form name="radiosearch" onSubmit="return myFunction();">
<input type="text" name="searchterms" size="20">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
<br />
<input type="radio" name="engine" value="http://chelmsford.mvlc.org/search/keyword/" checked>Catalog</input> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="engine" value="http://chelmsfordlibrary.org/?s=">Site</input>
</form>
```

How can I merge or correct these so one bit of code will work in all browsers?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the debug console in IE or Safari that would offer you a clue what is going wrong there?

Comment: Also, `escape()` has been deprecated - you probably want to use `encodeURIComponent()` instead or maybe you just just be doing `window.location.href = encodeURI(text + term)` instead.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 - unfortunately no, debuggers have not offered any help.  What happens in IE is that "undefined" and then whatever search term I entered is appended to the end of the current URL, rather than swapping the search engine string and search term for the window.location.  I'll keep working - thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using non-standard ways of getting the radio button value.  I'd suggest this which works in Chrome, IE and Firefox (I don't have the ability to try Safari, but it should work there too):

```
function dosearch() {
    var sf = document.searchform;
    var searchLocation = sf.querySelector('input[name="sengines"]:checked').value;
    window.location.href = searchLocation + encodeURIComponent(sf.searchterms.value);
    return false;
}
```

And, here's a working demo that logs the URL it would go to: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/h873sfgw/

---

FYI, an old-fashioned way to get the value of the radio button group, involves manually iterating through each radio button until you find the one that is `.checked`.  You can do that with a function as described here: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/get-selected.php

---

Here's the code for one of the above "old-fashioned" ways to solve this that works in old versions of IE:

```js
function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function dosearch() {
    var form = document.getElementById("searchform");
    var terms = document.getElementById("searchterms")
    var searchLocation = getRadioValue(form, "sengines");
    //window.location.href = searchLocation + encodeURIComponent(terms.value);
    log(searchLocation + encodeURIComponent(terms.value));
    return false;
}

function getRadioValue(formObj, groupName) {
    var inputs = formObj.getElementsByTagName("input"), item;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        item = inputs[i];
        if (item.type === "radio" && item.name === groupName && item.checked) {
            return item.value;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="searchform" name="searchform" onsubmit="return dosearch();">
<input type="text" id="searchterms" name="searchterms" size="20">
<input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search"">
<br />
<input type="radio" name="sengines" checked value="http://chelmsford.mvlc.org/search/keyword/">Catalog &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="sengines" value="http://chelmsfordlibrary.org/?s=">Site
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks again, but I am still struggling.  I've been working with the code you provided here, but it won't work for me in IE9 (which is what is installed here).  Instead of replacing the window.location with the new URL built by the script, it just appends the variables to the end of the current url.  I've also tried different window.location methods from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872598/window-location-href-not-working-in-ie-11 but no luck yet.  I see your demo logging correctly for me in IE, but trying the script live successfully is still elusive.

Comment: @herzogbr - Here's as generic a version as I can find that should work in IE9: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/foo73u44/.  Node the changes to the HTML too.

Comment: @herzogbr - and here's an actual web page that works in IE9 (I tested it) with a couple different versions of the code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7909102/ie9-form-test.html and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7909102/ie9-form-test2.html

Comment: that's great!  After some quick testing it works in all the browsers I have installed here, so I'll work on it more thoroughly next week and hopefully roll it out soon.  Thank you very much for doing this, it really helps me out!